# Posting data to MVC controller and then pop up bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, bootstrap-modal

I have a strongly typed view where I get data from user and I post the form data to a controller method. Now, the controller method performs some tasks and sends back some data to the same view, which I want to display as a bootstrap modal. I know how to implement modal, but it is not showing up on page load. Can anyone post a simple example to achieve the same?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should follow the steps as below:

1 - Post you data with Jquery ajax.

2 - Perform you operation in controller method and return the html you want to display in pop up.

3 - In Ajax success, open pop up with html which you got as response.

Hope this help.